# SQL Server 2016 on Microsoft Failover cluster

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

Do I need SQL Server 2016 Enterprise Edition for installing it on a Microsoft failover cluster?

Comment: Regardless if you're trying to run an Availaiblity Group or a traditional Failover Clustered Instance (FCI), your answer is "No".  Enterprise Edition is **not** required for the installation.  Standard edition will only allow you to run a [Basic Availability Group](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt614935.aspx) or a FCI in a 2-node configuration at most, but if that's all you need you shouldn't have any issues.

Answer (score 2):

No. You can setup a two node failover cluster with the standard edition of SQL Server. Any more than that and you need the enterprise edition.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/cloud-platform/sql-server-editions

Answer (score 2):

No, you can run a two node Always On failover cluster instance using Standard Edition. See the "RDBMS High Availability" section of https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993.aspx